# Why do special characters in a batch file print as a question mark?

Tags: windows, batch-file, character-encoding, windows-console

So I was working on a batch file game a while ago, and for some reason it prints a question mark symbol instead of the smiley face symbol (which you get when you press Ctrl+A in a command prompt).

[My Program ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRcY7.png)

I have the same problem with these others symbols:

```
ctrl+a Smiley face
ctrl+b Dark smiley face
ctrl+d Diamond
ctrl+e Clover
ctrl+f Ace
ctrl+n Music symbol
crtl+o Some random circlish symbol
ctrl+p Left arrow
ctrl+q Right arrow
ctrl+r Up and Down arrows
ctrl+t Line wrap symbol
ctrl+u Double s
ctrl+v Thick underscore
ctrl+w Up and down arrow with a line at the bottom
ctrl+x Up arrow
ctrl+y Down arrow
```

Source from Instructables Article: How do you use special characters in cmd

[I tried it with cmd ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLoC5.png)

I am currently running Windows 10 Pro with the latest update. I have tried to find a solution to fix this problem but had no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of OEM [Alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) is misleading for codes 1-31 and 127. The system's OEM codepage is a superset of ASCII. However, this range of Alt codes doesn't input ASCII control characters, but rather the characters that old IBM PC systems would sometimes display and print for ASCII control characters. For example, Alt+1 enters "☺" (U+263A, white smiling face) instead of ASCII SOH (U+0001, start of heading). To compound this, the default behavior of `WideCharToMultiByte` when encoding such characters to the OEM codepage is to use the corresponding ASCII control character as the *best-fit* encoding. So a text editor may not warn you that what you see is not what you'll get.

The console doesn't display control characters as the old IBM PC graphics characters. It interprets some of them such as U+0009 (horizontal tab -- advance the cursor 8 spaces) and U+000D (carriage return -- advance the cursor to the beginning of the next line), but most of them are displayed as the current font's glyph for an unmapped character, such as a boxed question mark or an empty box. If you want to print "☺" to the console, then you should use the console's wide-character API, which works with Windows native Unicode (UTF-16LE) strings.

Fortunately CMD is a Unicode application, so there's no problem with printing "☺" to the console. The problem is what encoding to use for the batch script. The only general solution is to save the batch file as UTF-8 without a BOM (byte order mark). You'll need an IDE or text editor that can save UTF-8 without a BOM, such as Notepad++.

CMD decodes a batch script line by line using the legacy console codepage, which you can change to UTF-8 with the command `chcp.com 65001`. I advise against changing to UTF-8 permanently because, depending on the Windows version, the console has various bugs with codepage 65001. You can switch to UTF-8 temporarily to load non-ASCII strings as environment variables. Otherwise keep the rest of the batch file as strictly 7-bit ASCII to avoid localization problems.

Here's an example. There is probably a more generalized way to go about this than creating all of these local environment variables, but it's just to show that it works in principle.

**graphics_ctl.bat**

```
@echo off
REM ASCII Control-Character Graphics
REM File encoding: UTF-8 (no BOM)

REM Set the console to codepage 65001 (UTF-8).
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('chcp.com') do set "CONSOLE_CODEPAGE=%%a"
set "CONSOLE_CODEPAGE=%CONSOLE_CODEPAGE: =%"
chcp.com 65001 >NUL

set "GCTL_WHITE_SMILING_FACE=☺"
set "GCTL_BLACK_SMILING_FACE=☻"
set "GCTL_BLACK_HEART_SUIT=♥"
set "GCTL_BLACK_DIAMOND_SUIT=♦"
set "GCTL_BLACK_CLUB_SUIT=♣"
set "GCTL_BLACK_SPADE_SUIT=♠"
set "GCTL_BULLET=•"
set "GCTL_INVERSE_BULLET=◘"
set "GCTL_WHITE_CIRCLE=○"
set "GCTL_INVERSE_WHITE_CIRCLE=◙"
set "GCTL_MALE_SIGN=♂"
set "GCTL_FEMALE_SIGN=♀"
set "GCTL_EIGHTH_NOTE=♪"
set "GCTL_BEAMED_EIGHTH_NOTES=♫"
set "GCTL_WHITE_SUN_WITH_RAYS=☼"
set "GCTL_BLACK_RIGHT_POINTER=►"
set "GCTL_BLACK_LEFT_POINTER=◄"
set "GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW=↕"
set "GCTL_DOUBLE_EXCLAMATION_MARK=‼"
set "GCTL_PILCROW_SIGN=¶"
set "GCTL_SECTION_SIGN=§"
set "GCTL_BLACK_RECTANGLE=▬"
set "GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW_WITH_BASE=↨"
set "GCTL_UP_ARROW=↑"
set "GCTL_DOWN_ARROW=↓"
set "GCTL_RIGHT_ARROW=→"
set "GCTL_LEFT_ARROW=←"
set "GCTL_RIGHT_ANGLE=∟"
set "GCTL_LEFT_RIGHT_ARROW=↔"
set "GCTL_BLACK_UP_TRIANGLE=▲"
set "GCTL_BLACK_DOWN_TRIANGLE=▼"
set "GCTL_HOUSE=⌂"

REM Restore the previous console codepage.
chcp.com %CONSOLE_CODEPAGE% >NUL
```

**graphics_box.bat**

```
@echo off
REM Box-Drawing Graphics
REM File encoding: UTF-8 (no BOM)

REM Set the console to codepage 65001 (UTF-8).
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('chcp.com') do set "CONSOLE_CODEPAGE=%%a"
set "CONSOLE_CODEPAGE=%CONSOLE_CODEPAGE: =%"
chcp.com 65001 >NUL

set "GBOX_LIGHT_SHADE=░"
set "GBOX_MEDIUM_SHADE=▒"
set "GBOX_DARK_SHADE=▓"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL=│"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT=┤"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE=╡"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE=╢"
set "GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE=╖"
set "GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE=╕"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT=╣"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL=║"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_LEFT=╗"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_LEFT=╝"
set "GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE=╜"
set "GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE=╛"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_LEFT=┐"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_RIGHT=└"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL=┴"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL=┬"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT=├"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_HORIZONTAL=─"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL=┼"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE=╞"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE=╟"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_RIGHT=╚"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_RIGHT=╔"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL=╩"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL=╦"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT=╠"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_HORIZONTAL=═"
set "GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL=╬"
set "GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE=╧"
set "GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE=╨"
set "GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE=╤"
set "GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE=╥"
set "GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE=╙"
set "GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE=╘"
set "GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE=╒"
set "GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE=╓"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE=╫"
set "GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE=╪"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_LEFT=┘"
set "GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_RIGHT=┌"
set "GBOX_FULL_BLOCK=█"
set "GBOX_LOWER_HALF_BLOCK=▄"
set "GBOX_LEFT_HALF_BLOCK=▌"
set "GBOX_RIGHT_HALF_BLOCK=▐"
set "GBOX_UPPER_HALF_BLOCK=▀"

REM Restore the previous console codepage.
chcp.com %CONSOLE_CODEPAGE% >NUL
```

**graphics_test.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "scriptdir=%~dp0"
call "%scriptdir%\graphics_ctl.bat"
call "%scriptdir%\graphics_box.bat"

echo.
echo ASCII Control-Character Graphics
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo GCTL_WHITE_SMILING_FACE      = %GCTL_WHITE_SMILING_FACE%
echo GCTL_BLACK_SMILING_FACE      = %GCTL_BLACK_SMILING_FACE%
echo GCTL_BLACK_HEART_SUIT        = %GCTL_BLACK_HEART_SUIT%
echo GCTL_BLACK_DIAMOND_SUIT      = %GCTL_BLACK_DIAMOND_SUIT%
echo GCTL_BLACK_CLUB_SUIT         = %GCTL_BLACK_CLUB_SUIT%
echo GCTL_BLACK_SPADE_SUIT        = %GCTL_BLACK_SPADE_SUIT%
echo GCTL_BULLET                  = %GCTL_BULLET%
echo GCTL_INVERSE_BULLET          = %GCTL_INVERSE_BULLET%
echo GCTL_WHITE_CIRCLE            = %GCTL_WHITE_CIRCLE%
echo GCTL_INVERSE_WHITE_CIRCLE    = %GCTL_INVERSE_WHITE_CIRCLE%
echo GCTL_MALE_SIGN               = %GCTL_MALE_SIGN%
echo GCTL_FEMALE_SIGN             = %GCTL_FEMALE_SIGN%
echo GCTL_EIGHTH_NOTE             = %GCTL_EIGHTH_NOTE%
echo GCTL_BEAMED_EIGHTH_NOTES     = %GCTL_BEAMED_EIGHTH_NOTES%
echo GCTL_WHITE_SUN_WITH_RAYS     = %GCTL_WHITE_SUN_WITH_RAYS%
echo GCTL_BLACK_RIGHT_POINTER     = %GCTL_BLACK_RIGHT_POINTER%
echo GCTL_BLACK_LEFT_POINTER      = %GCTL_BLACK_LEFT_POINTER%
echo GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW           = %GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW%
echo GCTL_DOUBLE_EXCLAMATION_MARK = %GCTL_DOUBLE_EXCLAMATION_MARK%
echo GCTL_PILCROW_SIGN            = %GCTL_PILCROW_SIGN%
echo GCTL_SECTION_SIGN            = %GCTL_SECTION_SIGN%
echo GCTL_BLACK_RECTANGLE         = %GCTL_BLACK_RECTANGLE%
echo GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW_WITH_BASE = %GCTL_UP_DOWN_ARROW_WITH_BASE%
echo GCTL_UP_ARROW                = %GCTL_UP_ARROW%
echo GCTL_DOWN_ARROW              = %GCTL_DOWN_ARROW%
echo GCTL_RIGHT_ARROW             = %GCTL_RIGHT_ARROW%
echo GCTL_LEFT_ARROW              = %GCTL_LEFT_ARROW%
echo GCTL_RIGHT_ANGLE             = %GCTL_RIGHT_ANGLE%
echo GCTL_LEFT_RIGHT_ARROW        = %GCTL_LEFT_RIGHT_ARROW%
echo GCTL_BLACK_UP_TRIANGLE       = %GCTL_BLACK_UP_TRIANGLE%
echo GCTL_BLACK_DOWN_TRIANGLE     = %GCTL_BLACK_DOWN_TRIANGLE%
echo GCTL_HOUSE                   = %GCTL_HOUSE%

echo.
echo Box-Drawing Graphics
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo GBOX_LIGHT_SHADE                           = %GBOX_LIGHT_SHADE%
echo GBOX_MEDIUM_SHADE                          = %GBOX_MEDIUM_SHADE%
echo GBOX_DARK_SHADE                            = %GBOX_DARK_SHADE%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL                        = %GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT               = %GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE       = %GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE       = %GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE           = %GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE           = %GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT              = %GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL                       = %GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_LEFT                  = %GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_LEFT                    = %GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE             = %GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_LEFT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE             = %GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_LEFT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_LEFT                   = %GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_RIGHT                    = %GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL               = %GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL             = %GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT              = %GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_HORIZONTAL                      = %GBOX_LIGHT_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL         = %GBOX_LIGHT_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE      = %GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE      = %GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_RIGHT                   = %GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_RIGHT                 = %GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL              = %GBOX_DOUBLE_UP_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL            = %GBOX_DOUBLE_DOWN_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT             = %GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_HORIZONTAL                     = %GBOX_DOUBLE_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL        = %GBOX_DOUBLE_VERTICAL_AND_HORIZONTAL%
echo GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE       = %GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE       = %GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE     = %GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE     = %GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE            = %GBOX_UP_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE            = %GBOX_UP_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE          = %GBOX_DOWN_SINGLE_AND_RIGHT_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE          = %GBOX_DOWN_DOUBLE_AND_RIGHT_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE = %GBOX_VERTICAL_DOUBLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_SINGLE%
echo GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE = %GBOX_VERTICAL_SINGLE_AND_HORIZONTAL_DOUBLE%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_LEFT                     = %GBOX_LIGHT_UP_AND_LEFT%
echo GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_RIGHT                  = %GBOX_LIGHT_DOWN_AND_RIGHT%
echo GBOX_FULL_BLOCK                            = %GBOX_FULL_BLOCK%
echo GBOX_LOWER_HALF_BLOCK                      = %GBOX_LOWER_HALF_BLOCK%
echo GBOX_LEFT_HALF_BLOCK                       = %GBOX_LEFT_HALF_BLOCK%
echo GBOX_RIGHT_HALF_BLOCK                      = %GBOX_RIGHT_HALF_BLOCK%
echo GBOX_UPPER_HALF_BLOCK                      = %GBOX_UPPER_HALF_BLOCK%
```

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped me a lot! ☺

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your code page. You can check it by going on command prompt and typing chcp, which well display your code page. Search it up and you'll find a list of characters you can write. Basically, it'll tell you which "special" characters you can type in that will be displayed. For example, mines is 850 (like a lot of others) and so can't display smiley faces. You can change your code page by:

```
Open Windows Control Panel
Select Region and Language
Click on the Administrative tab
Under Language for non-Unicode programs, click on Change System Locale
Choose the locale
Click OK
```

That's all, I think. Hope I helped!

Comment: Interesting. I will take a look at that. Thank you for your response.